# Same origin policy, external script

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I'm reading about the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). I understand that the js on my page should not have access to methods (and more) defined in a js resource on a different domain. However, I must be misreading this. In my website, I have a script reference to the jquery library at the code.jquery.com domain,

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
```

and everything in that library *is* available to the js scripts on my site.

So, what am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 2):

The same-origin-policy says that you are not allowed to use objects etc. declared in another domains i.e. in an iframe.
It does not forbid to load a script from a domain and run the code locally. The variables in the jquery script are not from another domain, you just loaded the source code from there.

Answer (score 0):

Same Origin Policy affects `iframe`s and XHRs, `img` and `canvas`, among other things.

Pointing a `script` src to a different host, protocol or port is not in violation with this. This is useful, as we can use a CDN to serve the files and use JSONP for data transfer (before CORS can be used everywhere - thanks < IE8).

Comment: Can I see the source code of the js included via a script tag with src attribute?